# How to add proxy server settings in wifi router or access point

Tags: centos, wifi, proxy, router, squid

I have squid proxy server running in centos 8
i want to setup proxy server in wifi router or wireless access point which i can force wireless clients to go through proxy server.

Comment: So either do a transparent proxy using `iptables` or whatever layer above that your router OS has, or distribute proxy settings via DHCP (which some apps may use, and some apps may not).

Comment: as well as transproxying and dhcp settings, blocking direct access to ports 80 and 443 (except for the proxy, of course) provides very strong encouragement for users to configure their systems to use the proxy.